# invalid use of register in addressing mode

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, intel

How come `mov rax, [rbp + 8*r8]` is valid addresing, but `mov rax, [rbp - 8*r8]` isn't ? `mov rax, [rbp - 8]` is also fine. I couldn't find anything on a negative `scale*index` value being an issue. To me it seems it follows the SBI template. (I didn't wanna dump my code here since this is the only line of code I get an error for).

Comment: because the only scaling factors allowed are 1,2,4,8 not -1,-2,-4,-8

Comment: What about if `r8` contained a negative value ?

Comment: The contents of the register can be anything the scaling factor is limited.

Comment: @monolith937 Then you can still do `rbp + 8*r8`.  What `r8` contains doesn't matter.

Comment: It is documented in the basic architecture manual, section _3.7.5 Specifying an Offset_, in particular _Figure 3-11. Offset (or Effective Address) Computation_ and _"Each of these components can have either a positive or negative (2s complement) value, with the exception of the scaling factor."_.

Comment: See https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#SIB to understand why you can't have a negative scale: it's only a 2-bit field which can encode a left-shift of 0..3.  It would take 1 more bit to allow subtraction instead of addition.